# What is the purpose of drafting in nascar races?

Tags: auto-racing, nascar

Is there any strategy or reason to draft another car in NASCAR races?

Answer (score 6):

It saves fuel since the car in front has to spend more energy to cut through the air resistance while the car drafting does not (as much).

> The low-pressure wake behind a group's leading car reduces the aerodynamic resistance on the front of the trailing car allowing the second car to pull closer. As the second car nears the first it pushes high-pressure air forward so less fast-moving air hits the lead car's spoiler. The result is less drag for both cars, allowing faster speeds.

<sub>[Drafting (aerodynamics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_%28aerodynamics%29)</sub>